# Laravel Route basic: Get a route with old fashioned php params

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I would like to be able to get a route like this:http://something.com/search?q=random_search

When I do this:

```
Route::get('search/{q}', function($q) {
    return $q;
});
```

It will answer to http://something.com/search/random_search but it seems it doesn't work for what I expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Register your route without `{q}` and with a name.

Using closure:

```
Route::get('search', ['as' => 'search', function(){
    $q = Input::get('q');
    return $q;
}]);
```

Using controller:

```
Route::get('search', ['as' => 'search', 'uses' => 'SearchController@yourMethod']);
```

Then call the route by its name:

```
route('search', ['q' => 'search query']); // /search?q=search%20query
```

or

```
URL::route('search', ['q' => 'search query']);
```

Comment: Perfect! And to call a `SearchController` method with `$q` param ?

Comment: Replace the closure with `'uses' => '...'` if you are using a controller. See my updated answer. You will still need to use `Input::get('q')` in your controller method.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really keen on using URL GET:

```
Route::get('search', function() {
    $q = Input::get('q');
    return $q;
});
```